# The for loop overwrite the results of another loop and I get only the last result

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

My problem is that I get only the last results of the loop, it overwrites other results and show me only the last ones.

I need to obtain from the json some information about a list of songs. This information is stored in a variable resource_url. So first of all I need to take list of tracks:

```
r = rq.get(url + tag)
time.sleep(2)
list = json.loads(r.content)
```

I get the resource url of each track:

```
c2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["title", "resource_url"])

for i, row in enumerate(list["results"]):
    title = row["title"]
    master_url = row["resource_url"]
    c2.loc[i] = [title, resource_url]
```

Each track has several songs so I get the songs:

```
for i, row in enumerate(list["results"]):
    url = row['resource_url']
    r = rq.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    songs = json.loads(r.content)
```

And then I try to get the duration of each song:

```
c3 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["title", "duration"])

for i, row in enumerate(songs["list"]):
    title = row["title"]
    duration = row["duration"]
    c3.loc[i] = [title, duration]

c3.head(24)
```

I obtain only the information of the songs of the last track but I need to get all of them. They are overwritten.

Comment: You say you only get the songs of the "last track" without really saying what comprises the "last track", i.e. it is difficult to tell that from your variable names. I do notice that you have a loop wherein you have `songs = json.loads(r.content)`. Are you not repeatedly overlaying prior values of `songs` and keeping only the final value that is assigned in the loop? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Exactly I need to save all the values but my loop is incorrect and I dont know how to improve it to save all the values, all songs with all their duration

Comment: Well, prior to the loop create a list `songs_list = []`. Then in the loop append to the list thus: `songs_list.append(json.loads(r.content))`. You can now iterate over all this list with: `for songs in songs_list:`.

Comment: Another comment: You are calling enumerate which gives you variable `i` that counts 0, 1, 2, etc. But you are not using this variable for anything in the loop. Then why bother using enumerate?